# Toggle visibility between two elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this html table with `contents`, `sub-contents` and `sub-sub-content`, I want to hide all sub-content "inside" the content I'm clicking on.

```
<table>
  <tr class='content'>
    <td>Things and things...</td>
  <tr class='sub-content'>
  <tr class='sub-content'>
  <tr class='sub-sub-content'>
  <tr class='content'>
  <tr class='sub-content'>
  <tr class='sub-sub-content'>
  <tr class='sub-sub-content'>
  <tr class='sub-content'>
  <tr class='sub-sub-content'>
  <tr class='content'>
  ...
</table>
```

I'm trying to do this with jQuery, but I can't get it right. Actually I'm hiding all `sub` and `sub-sub` after the clicked `content`, but I want to hide only `sub`/`sub-sub` from clicked `content` to next `content`.

```
$('.content').on('click', function() {
    var element = $(this).next('.content');
    $(this).nextUntil(element, '.sub-content').toggle();
    $(this).nextUntil(element, '.sub-sub-content').toggle();
});
```

I don't get what I'm missing here.

Comment: I'm not 100% clear what you are asking here.  If you only want to hide the sub-sub content, then only toggle that?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Do you have tr's inside of other tr's? Or did you just forget to include the </tr>'s?

Comment: Those TR has some idents, as a tree structure. When I click on a tr.content, I want to toggle all next sub-content and sub-sub-content until the next content.

Comment: Could you show exactly the table structure

Comment: Nope, those TR has not TR inside. It's just a visual effect about "what contains what", and I have to work with this structure.

Comment: @Devima I know it's confusing, but it's really as I posted it. In a correct way, it should be a <tr class='content'><tr class='sub-content'><tr class='sub-sbu-content'></tr></tr></tr> style, but it's not a parent/child structure, they are all on the same level.

Comment: Have you see the answer of mifi79?

Comment: Yes, I just tried it on my structure first to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may be overcomplicating it slightly... Try this instead:

```
$('.content').on('click', function() {
    $(this).nextUntil('.content').toggle();
});
```

Here is the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mifi79/KNED6/2/

Comment: @mifi79:you could simply use  $(this).nextUntil('.content').toggle();

Comment: @Devima Indeed I can. I think I too started overcomplicating as before I colored the tr.content I couldn't tell what was toggling. I've updated with the new, improved simplification.

Answer (score 0):

For me the best way is [FIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/videma/Pvv9Z/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.content').on('click', function() {
        $(this).nextUntil('.content').toggle();
    });

})
</script>
```